# Backbone: Designing an HTML designer app

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have a personal project, I want to make a simple editor for modelating an HTML page, nothing fancy, but the idea is to create something like a Windows Forms editor, where you can click buttons and add elements to the page, then change the settings and such. It doesn't really need to have drag-and-drop, just the ability to add elements inside each other.

The UI looks something like this

```
   v--- elements panel
 _______________________________________
| ELEMENTS |                            |
|          |     ___________________    | <- canvas
|   div    |    |                   |   |
|   img    |    |    IM A DIV       |   |
|    h1    |    |                   |   |
|----------|    |___________________|   |
| PROPS    |                            |
|          |                            |
| width:   |                            |
| height:  |                            |
|          |                            |
|          |                            |
|          |                            |
|__________|____________________________|
  ^--- properties panel
```

So when you click 'div', it adds a div to the canvas. The canvas can have only one element selected, of course, the properties panel reflects the properties of the currently selected element, when updated, they reflect the changes in the canvas.

If you click 'img' while the div is selected, it inserts it onto the div, if not, just to the root canvas.

The problem I have is that I don't really know how to design the application using Backbone.

They way I see it so far...

### Collections

So far I think I can get away with only one collection of elements, for the canvas view

### Views

There are three views, the element panel, the properties panel and the canvas, the latter beeing the most complicated.

### Models

Here is where I get confused, if I'm not mistaken, models are basically the entities from my app, in this case, html elements of different types (div, img, h1, etc). The canvas view holds a Collection of Element models.

As views reflect the state of the models, the canvas view should draw all the elements in the collection, as each model is of different type, it should draw them accordingly (a div should be rendered differently than an img).

Now, **how exactly does the view do render the elements?** Does each model store data on how it should be displayed, or does the view just knows how to render each element type?

Answer (score 1):

Backbone Views are what you make of them. From [the docs](http://backbonejs.org/#View) "Backbone views are almost more convention than they are code — they don't determine anything about your HTML or CSS for you, and can be used with any JavaScript templating library.".

You might want to look into the [Marionette Collection View](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/docs/marionette.collectionview.md). It supports [dynamically deciding which view to use](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/docs/marionette.collectionview.md#collectionviews-builditemview) for each model in the collection.

Here is [an example jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/somethingkindawierd/y8cdN/) showing a collection view rendering each model with a different item view based on the model's data. The model's only hold data relevant to their element type. The collection view is responsible for the decision of which item view to use.

The relevant bit of code is here:

```
var CollectionView = Marionette.CollectionView.extend({

    // Determine the default view for each item.
    itemView: BlockItemView,

    // Dynamically change the item view for each model as needed
    buildItemView: function(item, ItemViewType, itemViewOptions){
        // build the final list of options for the item view type
        var options = _.extend({
            model: item,
            tagName: item.get('tagName')
        }, itemViewOptions);

        var view;

        // Change the item's view based on the options...
        if(item.get('display') === 'inline') {
            view = new InlineItemView(options);
        }
        else {
            // defaults to BlockItemView
            view = new ItemViewType(options);
        }

        return view;
    }
});
```